# T-SQL Regex for social security number (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to find invalid social security numbers in a `varchar` field in a SQL Server 2008 database table. (Valid SSNs are being defined by being in the format `###-##-####` - doesn't matter what the numbers are, as long as they are in that "3-digit dash 2-digit dash 4-digit" pattern.

I do have a working regex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE ssn NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

That does find the invalid SSNs in the column, but I know (okay - I'm pretty sure) that there is a way to shorten that to indicate that the previous pattern can have x iterations.

I thought this would work:

```
'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}'
```

But it doesn't.

Is there a shorter regex than the one above in the select, or not? Or perhaps there is, but T-SQL/SQL Server 2008 doesn't support it!?

Comment: TSQL doesn't have native Regex support. It supports `LIKE` which you're using but that's a very simple language - not really regex at all. A better plan might be to store just 9 digits (quite simple to create constraints for that) and just insert the dashes when *displaying* the SSN - unless you actually need to support storing invalid data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to get a shorter variant of your LIKE expression, then the answer is no.

In [T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), you can only use the following wildcards in the *pattern*:

> **%**
>    - Any string of zero or more characters.
>   `WHERE title LIKE '%computer%'` finds all book titles with the word `computer` anywhere in the book title.
>
> **_ (underscore)**
>   Any single character.
>   `WHERE au_fname LIKE '_ean'` finds all four-letter first names that end with `ean` (Dean, Sean, and so on).
>   
> **[ ]**
>   Any single character within the specified range (`[a-f]`) or set (`[abcdef]`).
>   `WHERE au_lname LIKE '[C-P]arsen'` finds author last names ending with `arsen` and starting with any single character between `C` and `P`, for example `Carsen`, `Larsen`, `Karsen`, and so on. In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary depending on the sorting rules of the collation.
>   
> **[^]**
>   Any single character not within the specified range (`[^a-f]`) or set (`[^abcdef]`).

So, your `LIKE` statement is already the shortest possible expression. No limiting quantifiers can be used (those like `{min,max}`), not shorthand classes like `\d`.

If you were using MySQL, you could use a richer set of regex utilities, but it is not the case.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation, stribizhev.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use another solution like this:

```
-- Use `REPLICATE` if you really want to use a number to repeat
Declare @rgx nvarchar(max) = REPLICATE('#', 3) + '-' +
                             REPLICATE('#', 2) + '-' +
                             REPLICATE('#', 4);

-- or use your simple format string
Declare @rgx nvarchar(max) = '###-##-####';

-- then use this to get your final `LIKE` string.
Set @rgx = REPLACE(@rgx, '#', '[0-9]');
```

And you can also use something like `'_'` for characters then replace it with `[A-Z]` and so on.

Comment: What advantage does this confer to the OP?