# Finding a SSN in a text area

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a huge VARCHAR field, that is a body of an email. There could be any sort of text on either side of the email. I want to see if anyone listed their Social security number anywhere in the text.

In the WHERE clause, I tried

```
WHERE X.Description LIKE '%___-__-____%'
```

Is there a way to find a numeric string that looks like 111-11-1111 or 111 11 1111

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And if you find that pattern how can you be certain it is an SSN?

Comment: I.e. are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer will not be the same for those two products...

Comment: SSNs might be separated by spaces and not by hyphens in text.

Comment: SSNs might not be separated at all....

Answer (score 1):

use regex

[How to detect if a string contains at least a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558825/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-at-least-a-number)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

```
WHERE X.Description LIKE ''[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

[T-SQL Regex for social security number (SQL Server 2008 R2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788137/t-sql-regex-for-social-security-number-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE X.Description LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can guarantee that the separator for SSNs is always a hyphen.  In SQL Server, you could find examples using `like`:

```
where X.Description LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][- ][0-9][0-9][0-9][- ][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

In MySQL, you would use regular expressions:

```
where X.Description regexp '[0-9]{3}[- ][0-9]{3}[- ]{4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a space between each bracket and % to be safe like this:

```
WHERE X.Description LIKE '% [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
```

Otherwise the code would incorrectly think something like this is an SSN: 12343444-76-878787878